# CORS error for Post requests Node.js and React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets

My get requests for the code work but when it comes to the post requests, I get a cors error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api.com' from origin 'client.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've literally tried everything cors related to solve this and I keep getting the same results. I'm wondering if it's because of my socket server? It's frustrating.

my node code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const session = require("cookie-session");
const cors = require("cors");
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});
const multer = require('multer');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
let path = require('path');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
  session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: "shhhhhh",
  })
);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});



app.use(cors());

const {
  registerTeacher,
  loginTeacher,
  getOneTeacher,
  getAllTeachers,
  postAvailibility,
  deleteExpired
} = require("./teachers");

const {
  loginStudent,
  registerStudent,
  getOneStudent,
  bookTeacher,
} = require("./students");

const { postMessage, getMessages } = require("./classes");

///images
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'images');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {   
      cb(null, uuidv4() + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  const allowedFileTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png'];
  if(allowedFileTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
      cb(null, true);
  } else {
      cb(null, false);
  }
}

let upload = multer({ storage, fileFilter });

////teacher routes
app.post("/api/teachers/register", upload.single('photo'), registerTeacher);
app.post("/api/teachers/login", loginTeacher);
app.get("/api/teachers/:teacherId", getOneTeacher);
app.post("/api/teachers/:teacherId/calender", postAvailibility);
app.delete("/api/teachers/:teacherId/calender", deleteExpired)

///student routes
app.post("/api/students/register", upload.single('photo'), registerStudent);
app.post("/api/students/login", loginStudent);
app.get("/api/students/:studentId", getOneStudent);
app.get("/api/students/:studentId/ourteachers", getAllTeachers);
app.post("/api/students/:studentId/ourteachers/:teacherId", bookTeacher);


///Class Routes for getting messages only
app.put("/api/:classId/:studentId/:teacherId", postMessage);
app.get("/api/:classId/:studentId/:teacherId", getMessages);

////socket
let users = [];

const addUser = (userId, socketId) => {
  !users.some((user) => user.userId === userId) &&
    users.push({ userId, socketId });
};

const removeUser = (socketId) => {
  users = users.filter((user) => user.socketId !== socketId);
};

const getUser = (userId) => {
  return users.find((user) => user.userId === userId);
};

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  ///connected
  ///take userId and socketId
  socket.on("addUser", (userId) => {
    addUser(userId, socket.id);
    io.emit("getUsers", users);
  });

  ///send and get message
  socket.on("sendMessage", ({ senderId, receiverId, text }) => {
    const user = getUser(receiverId);
    io.to(user.socketId).emit("getMessage", {
      senderId,
      text,
    });
  });

  socket.emit("me", socket.id);

  socket.on("callUser", (data) => {
    io.to(data.userToCall).emit("callUser", {
      signal: data.signalData,
      from: data.from,
      name: data.name,
    });
  });

  socket.on("answerCall", (data) => {
    io.to(data.to).emit("callAccepted", data.signal);
  });

  ///for mouse

  socket.on("sendLines", (data) => {
    io.to(data.to).emit("getLines", data.lines);
  });

  socket.on("clearLines", (data) => {
    io.to(data.to).emit("getClearLines", data.lines);
  });

  ///for slides

  socket.on('sendSlidePosition', (data)=>{
    io.to(data.to).emit('getSlidePosition', data.slidePosition)
  })

  socket.on('sendAllow', (data)=>{
    io.to(data.to).emit('getAllow', data.data)
  })

  ///disconnected
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User disconnected");
    removeUser(socket.id);
    io.emit("getUsers", users);
  });
});

let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 5000;
}

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Successful port connection");
});
```

my react code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { FormControl, Input, Button } from "@material-ui/core";

function TeacherSignup() {
  let history = useHistory();

  const url =
    "myapi.com";
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    age: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    nationality: "",
    country: "",
    city: "",
    street: "",
    postalCode: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });

  function submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (data.password !== data.confirmPassword) {
      alert("passwords must match");
    }
    axios
      .post(url, {
        name: data.name,
        email: data.email,
        age: data.age,
        phoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
        country: data.country,
        city: data.city,
        street: data.street,
        password: data.password,
        postalCode: data.postalCode,
        nationality: data.nationality,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data._id);
        history.push(`/teachers/${res.data._id}`);
      });
  }

  function handle(e) {
    const newData = { ...data };
    newData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    setData(newData);
    console.log(newData);
  }

  return (
    <div className='login-form'>
      <h1>Register Teacher</h1>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => submit(e)}>
        <div className="login-input">
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
              id="name"
              value={data.name}
              placeholder="Name"
              type="text"
            ></Input>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="login-input">
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
              id="email"
              value={data.email}
              placeholder="Email"
              type="text"
            ></Input>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="login-input">
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
              id="age"
              value={data.age}
              placeholder="Age"
              type="text"
            ></Input>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="login-input">
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
              id="phoneNumber"
              value={data.phoneNumber}
              placeholder="Phone Number"
              type="text"
            ></Input>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="login-input">
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
              id="nationality"
              value={data.nationality}
              placeholder="Nationality"
              type="text"
            ></Input>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="login-input">
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
              id="country"
              value={data.country}
              placeholder="Country"
              type="text"
            ></Input>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="login-input">
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
              id="city"
              value={data.city}
              placeholder="City"
              type="text"
            ></Input>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="login-input">
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
              id="street"
              value={data.street}
              placeholder="Street"
              type="text"
            ></Input>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="login-input">
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
              id="postalCode"
              value={data.postalCode}
              placeholder="Postal Code"
              type="text"
            ></Input>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="login-input">
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
              id="password"
              value={data.password}
              placeholder="Password"
              type="text"
            ></Input>
          </FormControl>
        </div>
        <div className="login-input">
          <FormControl>
            <Input
              onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
              id="confirmPassword"
              value={data.confirmPassword}
              placeholder="Confirm Password"
              type="text"
            ></Input>
          </FormControl>
        </div>

        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TeacherSignup;
```

Comment: Why are you explicitly setting CORS response headers right before the `app.use(cors())` call? I would try removing that as it may be conflicting with `cors`.

Comment: I don't want to be picky, but the error is mentioning `api.com` and your react server is connecting to `myapi.com` Is this just a typo or are these two different servers?

Comment: And can you try removing the `app.use(cors())` and set a breakpoint in your custom cors handler (ie on `res.header.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`) to see if that breakpoint is hit? If it is hit, inspect the response on that particular request if it contains the ACAO header. If not (as the error suggests) there is something else interfering with your response and possibly resetting the headers ...

Comment: If the breakpoint isn't hit there is some other problem with your server setup which doesn't execute all middlewares. Then you should try reducing your server to a minimal example. For instance try removing `socket.io` and other middlewares and check if the problem still persists ... If you have working configuration, add back the various parts and see if the problem comes back ...

Comment: Can you also check in the browser, if there is a preflight (OPTIONS) request is sent and if yes, what is the result of this request ...

Comment: @derpirscher the status is 204

Comment: @derpirscher and yeah they're the same one

Comment: It's weird because I can post with login and other parts of the website. But the signup pages get the error

Comment: So you are telling that one POST works and the other one doesn't? That seems really weird. Have you tried minimizing your app? Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the server?

Comment: @RezaHojjati try running your react and node on the same port.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the explicit CORS headers set right before `app.use(cors())` and add `methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']` to your `io` configuration.

> Since Socket.IO v3, you need to explicitly enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

Comment: I tried but still didn't work. same error

Comment: Hard to say without more info about the exact error message. Make sure preflight requests are supported: `app.options('*', cors())`.

Comment: You might also be trying to pass credentials or custom headers that are not accepted by your `cors` configuration. Can you show the exact error?